# Writing an SQL query to filter and return data from numerous tables (many to many, one to many)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm building the functionality to filter results on a new website. Each result contains data from three separate tables (shown below as A, B, and C). The mapping tables (D through K) contains data that the majority of my filters are based on.

I'm looking to return rows with the columns of A.id, A.name, B.rating, C.price where D-K contains certain data on B. The filter content I have is a series of IDs from the mapping tables. I can have as little as no filters, or as many as 20 IDs I'd have to check before returning one A, B, C relationship. Further, there's a limit of 12 results to display per page.

Just thinking of the above fries my brain. I've drawn out the structure of the tables the best I can below. Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image: Database design]
.

**Schema Information** *Edit*

`A: id INT PRIMARY, name VARCHAR(255)`

`B: id INT PRIMARY, a_id INT, rating FLOAT`

`C: id INT PRIMARY, b_id INT, price DECIMAL(10, 2)`

Mapping Tables `D-K: b_id INT, ?_id INT`

`D-K: id INT PRIMARY, name VARCHAR(255)`

Comment: It'd help if you were able to actually show what the table schemas looked like with some example data.

Comment: Hello Amber, I've edited my post to include more schema information. The mapping table would contain two id columns that work as the primary key. As for data, I'm not sure what information is really needed. A has a name, B has a rating, C has a price, D-K mapping tables contain two id columns for their respective tables, and D-K normal tables contain a Name (which isn't important to the problem, or at least, I don't believe it is). Let me know if this helps. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to do some `JOIN`s.

```
SELECT A.name, B.rating, C.price
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.id = B.a_id
JOIN C ON B.id = C.b_id
```

Then, to do filtering from other tables, you'd join them in as well:

```
SELECT A.name, B.rating, C.price
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.id = B.a_id
JOIN C ON B.id = C.b_id
JOIN BDmapping ON B.id = BDmapping.b_id
JOIN BEmapping on B.id = BEmapping.b_id
WHERE BDmapping.d_id = <some value>
AND BEmapping.e_id = <some value>
```

Ideally, you only want to join in the tables you actually need to use for any given query - if you're not filtering on a given field, don't join in its table.

Comment: Thanks Amber, that definitely helps! One further question, if you have time. A can have many Bs and B can have many Cs. If I wanted to limit B and C to return one result--such as the highest rating B that references A and the lowest price of C that references B--what would be the best route to take? Thanks again!

Comment: Then you're getting to the point where you wind up needing to use sub-selects... at which point, it may be simpler and more intuitive to simply query for the relevant Bs and then do separate queries to get the matching As and Cs.

Comment: Sounds great, I'll do separate queries for the A and C tables as that makes more sense. Thanks again for your time and help!